# How to reset/clear/purge the DNS cache in OS X

Tags: macos, dns

OS X keeps a local cache of resolved DNS queries for a time defined by the DNS server. How to reset/clear/purge the DNS cache in OS X?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following Terminal command to reset the DNS cache in OS X

```
 sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo killall -QUIT -u _mdnsresponder
```

**discoveryd** will be restarted.

Worked for my laptop with Yosemite 10.10.3.